# Android Device for developing Android Apps

Tags: android, device, platform, google-nexus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to develop android applications on the device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527212/is-there-a-way-to-develop-android-applications-on-the-device)

Is there any way by which an Android device (preferably tablet with ICS) be used for Apps development? What advantage does google nexus have for the developers?

Comment: What do you think, how Android apps are tested?

Comment: Is there a way to code on these devices?

Comment: Are you asking if you can write code and compile code on an Android device?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. With ADB you can debug apps on the Android device from your PC.

If you meant writing an app on the device directly, I have seen apps that allow you to write and run Java as apps, but I can't imagine anyone making high-quality apps with something like this. I would avoid it and use Eclipse.

One advantage of the Nexus devices is supposed to be that it is "stock" Android-- without the weird junk like Touchwiz and Sense UI. Testing on stock would result in an app more likely to work across the other flavors of Android. The Galaxy Nexus had some extra stuff on it, but I can't remember what.

Another advantage is that the Nexus devices are supposed to get updates direct from Google without having to wait for carriers and manufacturers to modify the new versions before pushing them out.

Comment: Actually, a friend of mine has compiled GCC for ARM-linux-gnueabi and he's able to write and compile C programs directly on his Android phone.

Comment: That's really cool. Can you produce an app with that?

Comment: Yes I meant writing an app directly on the device, I guess cross platform development is the only option for serious dev work.

Comment: @Devon if you're able to get the headers+libs for the graphics, audio, GPS etc, then it is. :)

Comment: @Nikhil that's not really true. I also have an  on-device toolchain, though it's not Android but iOS (yes, GCC runs on iPhone/iPad as well!)